# Rails 4 building JSON with custom keys using JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I'm using JBuilder to build JSON response and now it look like:

```
 json.array!(@work_posts) do |work_post|
 json.extract! work_post, :post_title, :post_body, :salary, :urgently, :contact, :created_at, :updated_at
 json.contact do
   json.emails work_post.contact.emails
   json.phones work_post.contact.phones
   json.links work_post.contact.links
 end
end
```

And response look like:

```
[
  {
    "post_title": "Some work",
    "post_body": "work description",
    "salary": "5$/hour",
    "urgently": true,
    "contact": {
         "emails": "",
         "phones": "",
         "links": ""
              },
    "created_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00"
    }
]
```

I want add cutom keys to make response look like:

```
"result" : "success",   
"data" : [
  {
    "post_title": "Some work",
    "post_body": "work description",
    "salary": "5$/hour",
    "urgently": true,
    "contact": {
         "emails": "",
         "phones": "",
         "links": ""
              },
    "created_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00"
    }
]
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such question anywhere and I finally achieved what I wanted. Hope that it will be useful for someone. So the answer is very obvious: instead of using `json.array!` I should use what I exactly need => `json.data` and then I just need to put `json.result "success"` above. The result will be:

```
"result" : "success",   
"data" : [
 {
    "post_title": "Some work",
    "post_body": "work description",
    "salary": "5$/hour",
    "urgently": true,
    "contact": {
         "emails": "",
         "phones": "",
         "links": ""
          },
    "created_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-11T23:46:17.979+05:00"
  }
]
```